# r71: texture.needsUpdate = true doesn't update texture in firefox40

Tags: three.js

I need update the mesh's texture in my project, by changing the image's source in the texture. The code is below:

`mesh.material.map.image.src= "path/to/image";
mesh.material.map.texture.needsUpdate = true;`

The image has completely loaded. It works well in chrome, but not in firefox, the browser doesn't render new texture immediately, and i fixed it by:

`setTimeout( function(){ mesh.material.map.texture.needsUpdate = true; }, 100);`

I don't know why it can't update immediately in firefox, has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

since timeout fixes the issue, the needsUpdate flag is set back to false before the texture loads

you should probably use a loader for getting the texture

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("path/to/image");
```

it also has a callback for what happens when texture is loaded

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("path/to/image", THREE.UVMapping, onLoadCallback);
```

the callback gets loaded texture as parameter so you can add it to the material after load but the loader sets the textures needsUpdate flag to true itself so simple

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("path/to/image");
mesh.material.map = texture;
```

should suffice

Comment: Thanks, but
1. The function is THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture, not ImageUtils, haha.  
2. Create new texture may miss some properties of the old texture.  
3. Will it make some performance loss when create new texture every time.  
4. Your code fixes my issue, but not so perfectly.

Comment: Imperfection means there will be a frame that the mesh's surface is black after the old texture hides and before the new texture shows up

Comment: yes, it will be black for a short while, have you tried to  change the texture in the onLoad callback after it is really done loading?

Comment: my point is you set the texture to unloaded one, render cycle goes one iteration and paints it black, just after that it loads and sets update flag etc.. so if you make use of the onLoad callback it should go away (or is caused by something else)